# Showing there exists infinite $n$ such that $n! + 1$ is divisible by atleast two distinct primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a homework question.

I know there exists infinitely many primes. Let $n = p-1$ and so by Wilson's theorem we know there exists atleast one prime $p$ that divides $n! + 1$. I used wolframalpha and checked for a couple of $n = p-1$ values and all show me that there are in fact two distinct primes and one of them is in fact $p$.

How can I use this to conclude there exists a second prime $q$, $q \neq p$ such that $q$ dividies $n!+1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equivalently you can show that $(p-1)!+1=p^n$ has no solution for $p \geq 7$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}.$

Hint: $p^{n-1}+...+p+1=(p-2)!$ and $p-1|(p-2)!$ (since $p-1$ is composite), so what can you say about $n$ then? can you derive a contradiction?

Comment: why is showing the statement $(p-1)! + 1 = p^n$ has no solutions equivalent? And anything special about $p =7$ and $n=2$?

Comment: You have set $n=p-1$ so if you could rule out the existence of primes where $(p-1)!+1$ is only divisible by one prime you'd be done. That bounds come from the an inequality you'll get after determining a condition on $n.$

Comment: I am having a hard time with the bounds. I also am having a hard time understanding the hint. How can $(p-2)!$ be equal to a sum of primes with powers depending on $n$.

Comment: What is $p^{n-1}+...+p+1$ mod $p-1?$

Comment: for every power of $p$, it is $1 \pmod{p-1}$ so it is the summation of all the ones, exactly (n-1) of them.

Comment: No, you have $n$ $1$'s, right?

Comment: Yes, sorry. There are exactly n 1s.

Comment: So $p-1|n$ and you should show that $p^{p-1}>(p-1)!+1.$

Comment: Note also that you will need to fill in some details where Ehsan says "because $p-1$ is composite." It might help to consider the cases where $p-1$ is the product of at least two primes, and where $p-1$ is a power of 2, separately.

Comment: In other words, we have to show $p^n > (p-1)! + 1$? How does this give a bound on p? Sorry my questions probably seem dumb to you.

Comment: It doesn't give a bound on $p$. $(n-1)! < n^{n-1}$ for any integer $n>1$. You only need $p>5$ in order for $p-1\vert(p-2)!$.

Comment: okay I am very lost. If I may, I would like to recap. We know there exists atleast one prime $p$ that divides $n!+1$ by Wilson's theorem as long as $n=p-1$. I also $(p-2)! = 1 \mod{p}$. Now how does $p^{n-1} + \ldots + p + 1 = (p-2)!$? and what makes $(n-1)! < n^{n-1}$ true, and why do I need this?

I apologize for the stupid questions to which the answers are painfully obvious to you but not me.

Comment: Dear @Tyler Hilton, First step: if we show that there is no prime $p>5$ s.t. $(p-1)!+1=p^n$ then since $p|(p-1)!+1$ there has to be another distinct prime $q \neq p$ dividing $(p-1)!+1.$ right? So we want to prove that such $p$ does not exist.

Comment: For your second question, do you see why $(n-1)! \leq (n-1)^{n-1}$? Try writing out the products for a few $n$.

Comment: Second step: Assume the contrary that there is a $p>5$ s.t. for some $n$ we have $(p-1)!+1=p^n$ or indeed $(p-1)!=p^n-1=(p-1)(p^{n-1}+...+p+1)$ which is $(p-2)!=p^{n-1}+...+p+1.$ As you said, $p^{n-1}+...+p+1$ mod $p-1$ is $n$ and since $p-1|(p-2)!$ then $p-1|n$ and indeed $p-1 \leq n.$ Thus, it is enough to show that for $p>5,$ we have $p^{p-1}>(p-1)!+1.$