# Understanding the proof for showing that there are infinitely many $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $n!+1$ is divisible by at least two distinct primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

There is another post pertaining to this question; however, the other post does not address some specifics that concern me in the proof.

Proof: Let $n=p-1, p \geq 7$. Then $p|(p-1)!+1$. We will show that $(p-1)!+1=p^n$ has no solutions.

Suppose not. Suppose $(p-1)! + 1 = p^n$ has a solution for $p\geq 7$. Then $(p-1)! =p^n-1  = (p-1)(p^{n-1}+\cdots+p+1)$. So $(p-2)!\equiv n (\mod p-1)$.

Now suppose that $(p-1)|n$. Then $p-1\leq n$. So $(p-1)!+1<p^{p-1}\leq p^n$. Hence, there are no solutions.

It remains to show that $(p-1)|(p-2)!$. But $p-1=2m$ means $2m|(p-2)!$. QED

> Questions:
>
> 1. My understanding is that at the start of the proof, Wilson's theorem is used to show that at least one prime divides $n!+1$.
> 2. Why do we want to show that $(p-1)!+1=p^n$ has no solutions? The way I see it is that $p^n$ is composite, and we are basically saying that $p^n\nmid (p-1)!+1$, so no composite number divides $n! +1$. But how and where in the proof do we actually show that another prime $q \neq p$ divides $n!+1$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe the title needs some reordering?

Comment: @Emisor fixed thanks

Comment: Are you sure you got the problem right? $4!+1=25$. If the mentioned "other post" is [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/303732/showing-there-exists-infinite-n-such-that-n-1-is-divisible-by-atleast-two?rq=1), it says something different.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli oops, I forgot to add in that $p\geq 7$.

Comment: Ok, but you *also* seem to assume among the hypothesis that $n-1$ is prime (right when you say "then $p\mid (p-1)!+1$" ).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli That's a typo, the proof starts the same, with $n=p-1$ rather than $p=n-1$, and that is the other post I am referring to. Thanks.

Comment: @Lucas You want infinitely many $n$ such that $n!+1$ is divisible by at least two distinct primes. So you try looking at $n$ where $n+1$ is prime. Wilson's theorem tells you that $(p-1)!+1$ is divisible by $p$, It is clearly bigger than $p$ so either it is a power of $p$ or it is divisible by another prime as well.  So if you can show it is not a power of $p$ then you are home.

Comment: I don't like the last line about $(p-1)|(p-2)!.$... It's true because $(p-1)/2$ is an integer greater than $2$ (because $p$ is prime and $p>5$) and less than $p-2$ (for the same reason), so $2$ and $(p-1)/2$ both occur as different terms in the product $\prod_{j=1}^{p-2}(j).$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to show that at least two primes divide $n!+1$.

What is the exact opposite of this?

"$n!+1$ has only one prime divisor, i.e. $n!+1$ is a power of some prime number."

Now, suppose $(p-1)!+1$ is power of a prime number for some $p\ge 7$. However, we already know that $p|(p-1)!+1$, so, if $(p-1)!+1$ is power of a prime number, it needs to be $p^n$, for some $p$. Your proof shows that this is not possible, although you should've specified that as $p\ge 7$, $p-1>4$, so, $m>2$.

Thus, $(p-1)!+1$ has at least two different prime divisors for all prime number $p\ge7$. As there are infinitely many prime numbers greater than $7$, we're done.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $ p $ is a prime and $ p \geq 7\ $. I think that Lucas' proof  (above) only shows that $  (p-1)!+ 1 \neq p^{p-1} $. We prove that
 $  (p-1)!+ 1 \neq p^{k}$, for $  k \geq 1 $. Then, since, by Wilson's Theorem,  $ p \mid (p-1)!+1 $, it follows that at least two distinct primes divide $ (p-1)!+1$. Lower-case Latin letters denote non-negative integers.

Lemma 1. If $ $$ n\geq 7 $ and $n$ is odd, then, $ n-1 \mid (n-2)! $.

Proof. Let $t = \frac{n-1}{2} \in Z $. Then, $2<{t} \leq {n-2}$. Lemma 1 follows, since $n-1=2t\blacksquare$

Lemma 2. If $ $ $ 2 \leq t \leq n$, then, $n^t-n^{t-1} \geq t!$

Proof. If $n \geq 2$, then $n^2-n = (n - \frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4} \geq (2 - \frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4} = 2!$  . Thus, Lemma 2 holds for

$t=2$. Suppose Lemma 2 held for some $t$, where $2 \leq t < n$. Then,

$n^{t+1} - n^t =n(n^t-n^{t-1}) \geq n(t!) \geq (t+1)!$. So, Lemma 2 holds by  induction on $t\blacksquare$

Suppose $(p-1)!+1=p^k.$ Clearly, $k>0$. Also, $p \equiv 1$(Mod $ p-1$). Therefore,

(1)  $p^t \equiv 1^t = 1$ (Mod $p-1$), for $t \geq 0$.

$(p-1)! = p^{k} - 1= (p-1) \sum_{t=0}^{k-1}p^{t}$. Dividing this by $p-1$ and using (1) yields

$(p - 2)! = \sum_{t=0}^{k-1}p^{t} \equiv \sum_{t=0}^{k-1}1 = k$(Mod $p-1$). So, $p -1\mid k$, by Lemma 1. Hence, $k \geq p-1$,

since $k > 0$. Therefore, by Lemma 2,with $n = p$ and $t = p-1$,

$(p-1)!+1=p^k \geq p^{p-1} \geq (p-1)! + p^{p-2} > (p-1)! + 1$, a contradiction$\blacksquare$